# RegExp and preg_match for emails also allow *@domain.*

Tags: php, javascript, regex, email, preg-match

Helllo,

I'm Using this for validating emails:

```
JavaScript:

RegExp(/^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/);

PHP:

preg_match("/^[_a-z0-9-]+(.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(.[a-z]{2,3})$/i", $email)
```

These could easily validate the string to be like blah@blahblah.blah, BUT I also want to allow `*@blahblah.blah`, How those 2 rules should be edited for this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You really shouldn't invent a new regex to validate e-mails. For example your regex wouldn't allow for .info-domains. See the answers at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address instead.

Comment: @sQVe The users are making filters which could control the emails they receive from, they might want to allow their company emails address, so they should be able to allow *@somedomain.com

Comment: @feeela But I just checked, this is also OK with .info domains, I found the rule in Google, seems so many users are using it, thanks for your link by the way, I will definitely read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In regards to your PHP question, I would actually recommend an entirely different approach: [filter_var](http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) is an excellent way to validate e-mail addresses and is part of the PHP modern framework. If you are running PHP 5.2+, that is.

Comment: Seems it's just what I needed, it validates the usual email addresses like blah@blah.blah, and also returns true on *@blah.blah, the only thing which is left is for java script, any ideas for that RegExp? thanks